# jquery toggle for multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Each searchbox activates on the click of a greennav. I need help making each of the searchboxe's toggle away if active while another 'greennav' is clicked on (activating a new searchbox"). The effect I'm looking for is the active searchbox to toggle off screen while the searchbox that gets activated by the nav toggles onto the screen. Currently my code half works. if you click the sequence: greennav, greennav2, greennav3 and greennav4 the activations work but when greennav4 is active and you click greennav it will not activate the effect and show the related box.

```
$(document).ready(function () {




   var green_norepeat = true;
    var green2_norepeat = true;
var green3_norepeat = true;
  var green4_norepeat = true;

function hide_all() {

        if (green_norepeat == false) { $('#searchBox').animate({ width: 'toggle' }); }
        if (green2_norepeat == false) { $('#searchBox2').animate({ width: 'toggle' });  }
        if (green3_norepeat == false) { $('#searchBox3').animate({ width: 'toggle' }); }
        if (green4_norepeat == false) { $('#searchBox4').animate({ width: 'toggle' }); }

}


$("#greennav").click(function () {

    if (green_norepeat == true) {
        hide_all();
        green_norepeat = false;
        $('#searchBox').animate({ width: 'toggle' });

    }
    else
    {
        green_norepeat = true;
         $('#searchBox').animate({ width: 'toggle' });

}
});




$("#greennav2").click(function () {

    if (green2_norepeat == true) {
        hide_all();
        green2_norepeat = false;
        $('#searchBox2').animate({ width: 'toggle' });
    }
    else
    {
        green2_norepeat = true;
        $('#searchBox2').animate({ width: 'toggle' });

}
});

$("#greennav3").click(function () {

    if (green3_norepeat == true) {
        hide_all();
        green3_norepeat = false;
        $('#searchBox3').animate({ width: 'toggle' });
    }
    else
    {
        green3_norepeat = true;
        $('#searchBox3').animate({ width: 'toggle' });

}
});

    $("#greennav4").click(function () {

    if (green4_norepeat == true) {
        hide_all();
        green4_norepeat = false;
        $('#searchBox4').animate({ width: 'toggle' });
    }
    else
    {
        green4_norepeat = true;
        $('#searchBox4').animate({ width: 'toggle' });

}
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed it around a bit. I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<button id="greennav1" >1</button><input id="searchBox1" style="display: none" /><br />
<button id="greennav2" >2</button><input id="searchBox2" style="display: none" /><br />
<button id="greennav3" >3</button><input id="searchBox3" style="display: none" /><br />
<button id="greennav4" >4</button><input id="searchBox4" style="display: none" />

$(document).ready(function () {

    var btn_width =  $('#searchBox1').width();
    hide([1,2,3,4])
    function hide(hide_ids){
        $.each(hide_ids, function(key, val){
            $('#searchBox'+val).animate({ width: 0 }, function(){$(this).hide()});

        });
    }

    function show(show_ids){
        $.each(show_ids, function(key, val){
            $('#searchBox'+val).show().animate({ width: btn_width });
        });
    }


    $("#greennav1").click(function () {
        hide([2,3,4]);
        show([1]);
    });

    $("#greennav2").click(function () {
        hide([1,3,4]);
        show([2]);
    });
    $("#greennav3").click(function () {
        hide([1,2,4]);
        show([3]);
    });
    $("#greennav4").click(function () {
        hide([1,2,3]);
        show([4]);
    });

});
```

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tqkLH/

You will be able to condense this code quite a lot, but I kept it close to your original approach on purpose.